# PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class Tigren\Core\API\License\LicenseAPI, because the name is already in use

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I am getting an error when i try to run **setup:upgrade** command [third-party module](https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/),

**PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Tigren\Core\API\License\LicenseAPI, because the name is already in use in app\code\Tigren\Ajaxcompare\view\frontend\web\css\source\LicenseAPI\LicenseApi.php on line 14**

Comment: Share code of this file

Comment: You mean  this file 
 --> app\code\Tigren\Ajaxcompare\view\frontend\web\css\source\LicenseAPI\LicenseApi.php

Comment: Yes check if there is any namespace spelling mistake

Comment: https://codeshare.io/amAgQp

Comment: I download the extension from https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/

Comment: May i know what is the error in this extension?

Comment: Just checking wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120903/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-zus).

Answer (score 0):

Inside Tigren->Core

1. Create a folder API -> Another folder -> License -> Create file LicenseApi.php

Inside this file add the code of file you shared with me in comments and save it

Then delete rest of files where same error occurs, because they place php files in web folder that's why it is not working